# Matlab Batch processing .csv file

Tags: matlab, csv, batch-processing

I am dealing with data analysis from .csv file using Matlab. I have to analyse data from hundreds of .csv file using the same formula for all the files. The output for the data will be stored in one matrix (nrow and ncolumn).

I have a problem where, when the computation is finished, the first column of the matrix gives the correct answer while rest of the columns give the wrong answer. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Here is my code.

```
  %% importing the csv file with selected column
  files=dir('*.csv');
  for r=1:length(files);
      LHR=importcsv(files(r).name);

      %% Calculation of SMD
      % Define These Value
      TAW=-216;
      RAW=-129;

      % The very first row of Soil Moisture Deficit
      for j=1
          SMD(j,r)=(LHR.RAIN(j)-LHR.PET(j));
          if SMD(j,r)>0;
              SMD(j,r)=0;
          elseif SMD(j,r)<RAW;
              SMD(j,r)=(LHR.RAIN(j)-(LHR.PET(j)*((TAW-SMD(j-1))/(TAW-RAW))));
          end
      end

      %for the following SMD Calculation
      for o=2:(numel(LHR.RAIN));
          SMD(o,r)=SMD(o-1)+(LHR.RAIN(o)-LHR.PET(o));
          % The SMD conditions
          if SMD(o,r)>0;
              SMD(o,r)=0;
          elseif SMD(o,r)<RAW;
              SMD(o,r)=SMD(o-1)+(LHR.RAIN(o)-(LHR.PET(o)*((TAW-SMD(o-1))/(TAW-RAW))));
          end  
      end
 end
```

Comment: What is the variable name of your output, `SMD`? What does 'wrong' mean in this context? Have you tried using [the debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to see what is being written at each step?

Comment: @excaza Yeah my output variable name is SMD, i am new to Matlab and never used debugger, will try to use debugger to to see what is written. What i am said wrong is the value that calculated is suppose to be different from what its shows, i tried to compare using excel calculation apparently only the first column value is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the third for loop with the following code. This should give you the correct answer.

```
%for the following SMD Calculation
          for o=2:(numel(LHR.RAIN));
              SMD(o,r)=SMD(o-1,r)+(LHR.RAIN(o)-LHR.PET(o));
              % The SMD conditions
              if SMD(o,r)>0;
                  SMD(o,r)=0;
              elseif SMD(o,r)<RAW;
                  SMD(o,r)=SMD(o-1,r)+(LHR.RAIN(o)-(LHR.PET(o)*((TAW-SMD(o-1,r))/(TAW-RAW))));
              end  
          end
     end
```

I shall explain you here. The SMD is a two dimensional matrix. In the third for loop of your code, you mentioned it as a vector `[SMD(o-1)]`. I have changed it to `[SMD(o-1,r)]`. I hope this should give you the right answer.